# Что с Canvas в TextVIew?

Tags: android, java

```
package com.example.test;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MyTextView myTextView= (MyTextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    myTextView.setText("DDSdasdaddadasdasadasaas");

}
}
package com.example.test;

public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    private Paint paint;

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),paint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Почему так получилось?

[image: asd]

1. Я понимаю, что там с размером что-то не то, но почему же TextView больше, чем Canvas?
2. Это глюк?

Comment: Дам вам совет, как начинающему разработчику, больше гуглите, на первый взгляд это будет занимать больше времени - но нет. Вы тут гораздо дольше ответа будете ждать.

Comment: @ANDRO, уважайте других участников сообщества.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, но попробуйте вместо `Paint.Style.STROKE` использовать `Paint.Style.FILL`  
Вроде `Paint.Style.STROKE` как раз рисует только контур (обводку), но не заполняет его.

П. С. Картинки под спойлер не прячутсся тут.  
Можете заливать их на левые хостинги, и сюда сбрасывать только ссылки, например

Comment: @ANDRO, это ваш баг, а не разрабов. Давайте я научу вас считать с нуля, как настоящего программиста;
    
    canvas.drawRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),paint);

Если имеется TextView размером 100х100, то getWidth() вернет 100, но индексы пикселей будут начинаться от 0, и заканчиваться 99, поэтому если вызвать    
`canvas.drawRect(0,0,100,100,paint);`, то правая и нижняя рамки выйдут за границы TextView и попросту не нарисуются.
    
Вы и правда думаете, что Android-разработали идиоты? Люди глупее нас с вами? И никто за все эти годы не заметил этот "баг" и не отрепортил его? Серьезно?

Comment: И да, для таких задач правильно будет не переопределять класс, а всего лишь поставить фон.